# Why does the readability of the program decrease the more we use setup?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Quoted from 《The Art of Unit Testing》, Second Edition, Page 34

- But know that the more you use [SetUp], the less readable your tests will be,
  because people will have to keep reading test code in two places in the file to understand how the test gets its instances and what type of each object the test is using. I tell my students, “Imagine that the readers of your test have never met you and never will.They arrive and read your tests two years after you’ve left the company. Every little thing you do to help them understand the code without needing to ask any questions is a big help. They probably have nobody around who can answer those questions, so you’re their only hope.” Making their eyes jump constantly between two regions of code to understand your test isn’t a good idea.

  ```
    using NUnit.Framework;
    [TestFixture] public class LogAnalyzerTests
    {
      private LogAnalyzer m_analyzer=null;
      [SetUp]
      public void Setup()
      {
         m_analyzer = new LogAnalyzer();
      }
      [Test]
      public void IsValidFileName_validFileLowerCased_ReturnsTrue()
      {
         bool result = m_analyzer.IsValidLogFileName("whatever.slf");

         Assert.IsTrue(result, "filename should be valid!");
      }
      [Test]
      public void IsValidFileName_validFileUpperCased_ReturnsTrue()
      {
         bool result = m_analyzer.IsValidLogFileName("whatever.SLF");

         Assert.IsTrue(result, "filename should be valid!");
      }
      [TearDown]
      public void TearDown()
      {
       //the line below is included to show an anti pattern.
       //This isn’t really needed. Don’t do it in real life.
      m_analyzer = null;
      }
  }
  ```

There are two issues：

1. Why does the readability of the program decrease the more we use setup?Why does I have to keep reading test code in two places in the file to understand how the test gets its instances and what type of each object the test is using
2. Why does the TearDown() isn’t really needed. Don’t do it in real life.

Comment: Creating  the class under test in the Setup method seems not helpful and easy maintainable. I use Setup/TearDown for two things. Maintaining infrastructure state. For example in Asp.Net code you often have a surround Activity that maintains the RequestId. I use Setup/Teardown to Start/Stop one. Its not a helpful thing to flood test within it hasn't really anything todo with the test it just needs to be there. Second one is reseting/clearing mocks. Only mock setup should be in the actual test not its reseting.

Comment: @Ralf The other parts of this book mention: To avoid the influence of different tests on each other's state, setup modules are used. NUnit will automatically clean up memory after completing a test, preventing interference between different tests and affecting the test results.

Comment: I'm not sure whats meant here with "modules" (maybe a complete class like the LogAnalyzerTests here) but in your example the two tests might affect each other if you didn't recreate the LogAnalyzer in Setup or the Test itself.

Comment: I think your quote explains it fairly well. But keep in mind that tests might be a fair bit of code, not the trivial example you are showing. Having to scroll up multiple screens to check something and then back again makes readability more difficult. But duplicating setup code in each test is also not ideal, so you should try to limit the setup to things that are actually common for all tests, and ideally to fairly simple things that can be easily understood without any need to reference it when reading the test.

Comment: @JonasH " Having to scroll up multiple screens to check something and then back again makes readability more difficult."-----Yes,it is.But does this matter with or without setup? Adding setup wouldn't make the code significantly longer and harder to read, would it?